# One-to-many and one-to-many relationship 1 laravel

Tags: laravel, one-to-many

i did this(sorry my english it's bad bad....)

controller:

```
public function index()
{
   $lessons = course::find(1)->lesson;
   return view('home',compact('lessons'));
}
```

model lesson

```
public function course() {
    return $this->belongsTo(Course::class);
}
```

model courses

```
public function lesson() {
   return $this->hasMany(Lesson::class);
}
```

blade

```
@foreach ($lessons as $lesson )

<h4>{{$lesson->title}}</h4>

@endforeach
```

in browser nothing appears
why?:(

Comment: maybe no course id 1 dont have any lession

Comment: Can you show us the tables involved and their content?

Comment: Schema::create('lessons', function (Blueprint $table) {
                $table->increments('id');
                $table->integer('user_id')->unsigned();
                $table->integer('course_id');
                $table->string('title');
                $table->string('slug')->nullable();
                $table->string('lessons_image')->nullable();
                $table->string('short_text')->nullable();
                $table->text('long_text')->nullable();
                $table->string('filename');
                $table->string('original_filename');

Comment: Schema::create('courses', function (Blueprint $table) {
                $table->increments('id');
                $table->integer('user_id')->unsigned();
                $table->string('title');
                $table->string('slug')->nullable();
                $table->text('descrption')->nullable();
                $table->string('course_image')->nullable();

Comment: when you try with tinker it shows me

Comment: what is the name of your blade file?

Comment: it's home.blade.php

Comment: add a `dd($lessons);` in the blade file. if it has lessons data try `dd($lessons->first());` and add results to the question.

Comment: Could you verify the column name for course id in lessons table?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First rename your lesson method with plural `lessons`.

```
// Course model

public function lessons()  // plural
{
    return $this->hasMany(Lesson::class);
}
```

Now get the lesson's collection.

```
public function index()
{
   $lessons = Course::find(1)->lessons;
   return view('home', compact('lessons'));
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
  @foreach ($lessons as $lesson )

  <h4>{{$lesson->course->title}}</h4>

 @endforeach
```

Answer (score -1):

Have you tried it like this:

```
return view('greeting')->with('lessons', $lessons);
```

Now you can call '$lessons' in your view. Take a look at this link
https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/views

Can you try to use `return $lessons;` and show me what it says?

Comment: Have you checked if lessons is greater than 0? Can you take a look at my updated answer?

Comment: with('lessons', $lessons) and view('view', compact('lessons')) is equivalent.

Comment: I know, but it's worth a try isn't it?